# How can i remove blank between rows in fast report table for browsers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fastreport, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am using Fastreport for mvc core project but i have a problem for created table in fastreport. My created table includes some blank between rows or column but there is no problem exporting the prepared report as pdf,excel etc.. I am designing on fastreport designer and showing previewing, there is no any problem.How can i overcome this problem? 
[image]

```
        WebReport webReport = new WebReport();

        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable table=new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("AD", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("SOYAD", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("TARIH", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        }

        dataSet.Tables.Add(table);

        // FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;

        FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;
        webReport.Report.Load("C:\\......\\isimsiz.frx");
        webReport.Report.RegisterData(table, "DATA");
        webReport.Report.GetDataSource("DATA").Enabled = true;
        var db = (DataBand)webReport.Report.FindObject("Data1");
        db.DataSource = webReport.Report.GetDataSource("DATA");
        webReport.Report.SetParameterValue("ParamAdi","Gökhan");

        webReport.Report.Prepare();





        ViewBag.WebReport = webReport;
```

Comment: This looks like a styling issue on the table, rather than anything to do with the data (as you say yourself, it exports just fine).

Comment: There is no problem designing for report, it works very well on our desktop project. But browsers show blank between rows and columns.Important issue is that viewing report on browser. If end-users do not like the design of report, they do not want to use our site.  @Moo-Juice

Comment: Then it may be a limitation of FastReports HTML Rendering.